# "Native Client is not allowed" on embedded Chrome app store app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I've verified and added the site serving the embedded Chrome app (and also installed the app from the store)... but for some reason, I still get "Native Client is not allowed" on the embed.

Comment: Interesting to see all those sponsored tags together :)

Comment: trying to get another arcane google tech to work to spec... apparently these were the only tags s/o would let me choose from!

Comment: It's possible that your user data for your app is stale, especially if it was originally installed during development before it was uploaded to the Chrome Web Store. Could you try installing your app in a fresh profile and seeing if it loads?